# What does "&" mean here in PHP?

Tags: php

Consider this PHP code:

```
call_user_func(array(&$this, 'method_name'), $args);
```

I know it means pass-by-reference when defining functions, but is it when calling a function?

Answer (score 22):

From the [Passing By Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) docs page:

> You can pass a variable by reference
> to a function so the function can
> modify the variable. The syntax is as
> follows:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
?>
```

> ...In recent versions of PHP you will
> get a warning saying that "call-time
> pass-by-reference" is deprecated when
> you use & in foo(&$a);

Comment: have a look at https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical/ for conceptual understanding.

Comment: I understand the question that this is known, the question is, why would you use & when calling a function (not when defining a function)?

Answer (score -3):

It's a pass-by-reference.

​​​​​

Comment: Am I right in thinking it no longer applies from PHP 5 onwards?

Comment: I know it mean pass-by-reference when defining functions,but is it when calling a function?

Comment: @Ian: Partly. Objects are always passed by reference, whereas anything else is copied. It does not make any sense with $this, but might be useful for large array, for example.

Answer (score -3):

```
call_user_func(array(&$this, 'method_name'), $args);
```

This code generating Notice:
Notice: Undefined variable: this

Here is a correct example:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
call_user_func('increment', $a);
echo $a."\n";

// You can use this instead
call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));
echo $a."\n";
?>
The above example will output:

0
1
```